# Checking if the mouse is within a window when using VMWare-Unity

Tags: winapi, vmware

In an application I'm working on, I have a notification window that pops up to inform the users about events. It's very similar to the new mail notification used by Outlook--it shows up for a few seconds and then goes away automatically. But, if the mouse is on top of the notification window, the window stays visible until the mouse leave the window area.

To see if the mouse is within the window, I'm using the [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API functions. These work great in most cases. But, I've discovered that they don't work as expected when I'm using the Unity mode of VMWare (where the application windows in the VM are made to appear outside of the VM). If the mouse is not within the area of the VM application, and is instead in an application running outside the VM, those Win32 API calls are still telling me that the mouse is in the VM.

As an example, when I'm running in Unity and the mouse is over my notification window, I get the following information from those two API calls:

```
Window Rect:
Left: 1190
Right: 1540
Top: 743
Bottom: 864

Mouse:
X: 1529
Y: 802
```

When the mouse is sitting over the Windows desktop or another non-VM application window, I get these results:

```
Window Rect:
Left: 1200
Right: 1550
Top: 748
Bottom: 869

Mouse:
X: 1547
Y: 799
```

As you can see, GetCursorPos is returning a mouse location that is within the screen rect of the window, so the notification never disappears, even though the mouse is not over it.

I've tried using the [GetCursorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to see if the cursor is showing, but that is returning a value of 1 in the flags variable in both cases. So, I'm at a loss of how to get this to work in Unity mode. Are there any other things I could check to detect this?

Comment: Why not have the notification window itself handle the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages? Then it will know if the mouse is inside of it and can act accordingly when needed. See this for an example: [Why is there no WM_MOUSEENTER message?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/13/55279.aspx)

Comment: I could try it, but I'm fairly certain the WM_MOUSELEAVE message won't fire, since the mouse is still within the window as far as Windows is concerned (at least based on the values being returned).